# I cannot pose my humanoid, even though it is rigged and parented

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, error, pose-mode

1. I have a mesh based humanoid with texture.
2. I added and adjusted the metarig.
3. I click body, then shift-click metarig.
4. I right click and do parent -> Armature Deform -> With Automatic Weights.

I try then to pose the model but the metarig is the only thing that moves. Seems like the mesh and the rig are not bound, despite looking like it in my scene collection pane, within the metarig's tree. (Body is inside the metarig's collection).

About to self-destruct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

while in object mode, select your object shift select (add select) your bone armature, then hit ctrl + p, with automatic wheigths.

But before you do this apply scale (ctrl+a) for both mesh and bones, people often forget it and that gives a lot of problems

Comment: this did not work. but thanks for the tip

Comment: if possible can you share the blend file, for humanoids its always done like that.
Maybe i can spot what goes wrong, before you selfdestruct :)
I know how terrible this can be.

Comment: @azu is righ the first modifier in your mesh modifiers ?
Also maybe just link your blend file, i might fix it,

Comment: Why are you parenting the mesh to the metarig? You're supposed to generate a final rig from the metarig, then either put the metarig aside afterwards or delete it. Then you parent the mesh to the final rig. The only purpose of the metarig is to tell the final rig what position all the joints should be in when the final rig generates.